# .NET WebClient DownloadFile using its own fileName?

Tags: c#, webclient

if filename in the Response Headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=ABC.txt
```

how can i get it and save file using it?

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())
{
 Client.DownloadFile("http://www.abc.com/file/song",path+"filename");
}
```

Comment: You would have to use a WebRequest instead, so that you could examine headers first.

Comment: Using HttpWebRequest seems need to read stream from response , then pharse Header's filename and save the file. In fact,I want to download file like browser works, but I can't find a better way..